# Probability of a ball to be drawn last in multiple independent draws.

Tags: probability

I have an urn with 5 different balls, let's call them A, B, C, D, E.
I will be drawing all the balls to make up an ordered sequence, let's say B, C, D, A, E.
I repeat the draw 7 times.

Now let's say I am worried that the draw is fixed so to favour a given ball to be drawn last; for example, I know that a ball has been drawn last 4 times over 7. Should I be worried?

I am thinking that the normal probability of a ball to be drawn last in one single draw is 1/5, so making the proportion the probability of it happening over 7 draws should be 20% still. Is it correct? Also, in case of a ball ending last 4 times over 7 we are looking at a probability of 4/7 (57.14%). Is it correct to compare 20% against 57% or am I missing something? Can I consider it an anomaly?

Now some specific questions I would like to (know how to) answer:

- What's the probability of a ball to be drawn last in one draw? I would say 1/5.
- What's the probability of a ball to be drawn last in two consecutive draws?
- What's the probability of a ball to be drawn last *n* times over the 7 draws?

Also, could you provide calculations/formulas for a generic scenario with *B* balls and *D* draws?

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that a specific ball will be drawn last is indeed $\frac15.$  This is just a sequence of [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) with probability of success $p=\frac15.$  The probability of exactly $k$ successes is $n$ trials is $${n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$ because there are ${n\choose k}$ ways to pick which of the $k$ trials will be successful, and, of course if we have $k$ successes (with probability $p$ each) we must have $n-k$ failures (with probability $1-p$ each.)

Comment: @DanielMathias Yes, thank you.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you! So the probability for this specific scenario is below 3%. But how can I determine if it is an anomaly? We can all see that it is a pretty low probability, but is it enough to say that the draws were fixed?

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/uR4WuQ0/comment/1066898387

Comment: Seriously, I'd say looking at it after the fact doesn't tell you a whole lot.  Strange things happen, after all.  If you contend that it's fixed and do an experiment, and the event of low probability that you predicted happens, then you have much better reason to suspect foul play.  That's more in the realm of statistics, something about which I don't know much.  You could ask another question.